# How to connect to a server via wifi device using a dialer(vpn)?

Tags: windows, vpn, router, internet, tp-link

**Question:** 
How to connect to a server via Wifi device using a dialer?

**Description:**

I have a dialer that I use to connect to my cable network server in order to access the internet. I connect using the Ethernet(STP) cable.

**Dialer:** is a software that takes in the userid/pwd and creates a vpn tunnel to the cable internet server.

I have a TP-Link router that converts the wire connection into wifi connection. I want to use the router, just get rid of the wires.

Is there is way that I can use the dialer via router to connect to my internet cable provider? (see following figure - structure wanted)

I would appreciate IP address schemes, logic, etc - whatever that may help.

Thanks in advance.

[image]
[http://img232.imageshack.us/img232/7305/tplink.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

Dialer? What dialer?

A lot depends on what VPN software you are using. MS IPSEC, by default verifies the addresses on the packets - and usually in this type of configuration, the router will perform masquerading - indeed, 192.168.0.0 is a private network address. That means you either need to terminate the IPSEC on the router or enable NAT-traversal on the IPSEC link.

I've previously found IPSEC to be a major PITA to get working even without these complications - and usually just use openvpn or stunnel - but most tunnelling protocols will work.

Comment: **Dialer:** is a software that takes in the userid/pwd and creates a vpn tunnel to the cable internet server. `I am lost!` out of your answer!